# Use a dataframe as a key to fill another according to one column values in R Studio

Tags: r

I am trying fill x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 into DF2 from DF1 according to DF1$x6. I have 800+ unique DF1$x6 observations. Thank you in advance

DF1:

```
    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 
    2  a  c  a  5  a1 
    o  5  y  7  I  a2 
    H  5  a  v  3  a3 
    0  8  I  a  3  a4
```

DF2

```
    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 
                   a4 
                   a2 
                   a4 
                   a1 
                   a1 
                   a4 
                   a3
```

To get a result below

DF2

```
    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 
    0  8  I  a  3  a4 
    o  5  y  7  I  a2
    0  8  I  a  3  a4 
    2  a  c  a  5  a1
    2  a  c  a  5  a1
    0  8  I  a  3  a4 
    H  5  a  v  3  a3
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your final desired result looks like?

Comment: Maybe to replace the first five columns you could try: `df2[, 1:5] <- df1[match(df2$x6, df1$x6), 1:5]`?

Comment: I can try that and trow in :ncol

Comment: Read : [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a merge/join operation:

```r
merge(DF2[,"x6",drop=FALSE], DF1, by = "x6", all.x = TRUE)
#   x6 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
# 1 a1  2  a  c  a  5
# 2 a1  2  a  c  a  5
# 3 a2  o  5  y  7  I
# 4 a3  H  5  a  v  3
# 5 a4  0  8  I  a  3
# 6 a4  0  8  I  a  3
# 7 a4  0  8  I  a  3
```

Or you can use `match` in a simplified join-like operaiton, as @Ben suggested in a comment:

```r
DF1[match(DF2$x6, DF1$x6),]
#     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
# 4    0  8  I  a  3 a4
# 2    o  5  y  7  I a2
# 4.1  0  8  I  a  3 a4
# 1    2  a  c  a  5 a1
# 1.1  2  a  c  a  5 a1
# 4.2  0  8  I  a  3 a4
# 3    H  5  a  v  3 a3
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do merge(DF2, DF1, by x6) and drop the .x columns to get the desired results.